# Why are there more scopes to accept in WP7 Live SKD than set?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I am experimenting with Windows Live SDK for Windows Phone and tried to access SkyDrive with some example code from the internet. Now I am a little confused about the Scopes attribute set in my xaml file:

```
<Microsoft_Live_Controls:SignInButton Content="SignInButton"
                                               ClientId="00000000XXXXXXX"
                                               Scopes="wl.skydrive_update"
                                               RedirectUri="https://oauth.live.com/desktop"
```

I could create my first folder after logging in and accepting the policy. From now on I was trying to read the root folder with this call:

```
GetAsync("me/skydrive/files");
```

But it permanently leads to an System.NotSupportedException in System.Windows.dll and the event handling code is never reached. I couldn't localize the mistake I made, so I tried to change the Scopes attribute, because different examples use different Scopes.

Now comes the confusing part. Every change I met to the Scopes attribute led to the same policy page. Even if I set it to "wl.basic" I had to accept the access and update of the skydrive policy.

I don't get it. I restarted the IDE and emulator and even rebooted my machine at the end.

Does anyone have an explanation for me?

And if there is someone who can help with the exception from above, please feel free to leave a comment.

Comment: I have still no idea why I see a policy where I also have to accept access to personal information, contacts and friends, but I found my mistake: Better use GetCompleted event with GetAsync. But the exception is still thrown between the call and the event.

Comment: Same here! No matter what scopes I set, I always get the same policy page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website caches the scopes the first time you connect to windows live.

So no matter how you change your sign-in Scopes afterwards, you always get the same policy page.

To force a new page you could delete the windows live application and create a new one, and us the new Client ID.

Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/messengerconnect/thread/37be752f-2ebf-4342-ab4e-0e5506415e61